# Angular click event to add class to specifically clicked element, while removing it from ones that aren't clicked

Tags: jquery, angular

How would I convert something like this from jQuery to Angular?

HTML

```
<div>
  <p class="question">Which would you like to select?</p>
  <div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 2</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer 3</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".answer").click(function(){
   $(".selectedAnswer").removeClass('selectedAnswer') //removes this from any previously selected answer
   $(this).addClass("selectedAnswer") //adds class to the new specific answer selected
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more flexible and dynamic solution is something like this:

**some.component.html**

```html
<div>
  <p class="question">Which would you like to select?</p>
  <div *ngFor="let answer of answers" 
    (click)="select(answer)" class="answer"
    [class.selectedAnswer]="selectedAnswer==answer">{{answer}}</div>
</div>
```

**some.component.ts**

```
// you can get your answer from some service
answers: string[] = ['Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3'];  
selectedAnswer: string = null;

/*select an answer*/
select(answer: string) {
this.selectedAnswer = answer;
}
```